# Запуск только подписанных файлов

Tags: c#, криптография

Нужно реализовать приложение, которое будет обрабатывать только подписанные файлы. Можно конечно самостоятельно шифровать файл AES, а сам ключ зашифровывать RSA, открытый ключ которого будет вбит внутрь приложения. Но может есть уже готовое решение, желательно с использованием шифрования эллиптических кривых?

Comment: Так запуск или обработка? )

Comment: @Kromster, я думал в данном случае это синонимы :)

Comment: Запускают исполняемые файлы (например ЕХЕ), а обрабатывают любые (например, TXT). Может быть вам достаточно архивировать их с паролем?

Comment: @Kromster не архивировать с паролем, а шифровать файл AES. Дальше ключ тоже как то надо безопасно хранить, тут выходит на сцену RSA.

Comment: А в чем проблема. Используй отсоединенную электроподпись. В main программы добавь её проверку